# Media images are not loading in template page when DEBUG=false in setti gs.py in django

Tags: python, html, django, media, django-urls

## facing error while debug is true in production

I hosted my website but there is a problem with the media files. The media files are not loading in the templates because I set **DEBUG = True** , in my settings.py file. What should I do now to fix this error ?

Comment: This is normal. Django does not serve static/media files in production, because it is inefficient and unsafe. You need to configure nginx/apache/... to serve these.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files